# Large query time for analytics purposes

Tags: sql, postgresql, analytics, postgresql-performance

I'm analyzing a 50GB (16M rows, 15 columns) table using PostgreSQL 9.4 using only select queries (no inset\updates). My server has 4 virtual sockets and 16GB RAM.
A typical query i'm using:

```
select y,count(z) from table where x in (select * from verySmallTable) group by y;
```

The result of the query are feed to a python script.

I have tried creating various indexes, but still each query can take 15 minutes to run. Additional, optimizing the DB is time consuming.

On the other hand, i'm using Tableau (using data extract) to retrieve similar information, and get a result in less than a minute. Hence, i conclude that with the right structure (automatically created), such analytics queries can be run very quickly.

I'm looking for a way to reduce the query run time, using PostgreSQL (i have Oracle licence as well), or some other open-source DB, or even some local solution in Python that i can load the data into, without having to optimize the structure to each query i run.

Comment: You are loading 50 Gbytes into Tableau and getting better performance than in Postgres?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info, then [edit] your question and add the missing information.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks i added the information. Gordon Linoff, yes, a simple "select (distinct(userName)) from table" for example, i'm not using an index on this column - that is part of the problem, as i explained i'm not necessarily looking to stick with PostgreSQL, it's just a single table.

Comment: @Guys: I think what Gordon meant was: did you really load the complete 50GB into Tableau? Tableau processes everything in memory if I'm not mistaken, so this sounds a bit strange.

Comment: To be accurate, i just created the extract again. The tables takes 42GB (on the DB), It took 2 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume this is your query:

```
select t.y, count(t.z)
from table t
where t.x in (select vst.x from verySmallTable vst)
group by t.y;
```

And that the `x` value in the small table are unique.  I would suggest writing the query as:

```
select t.y, count(t.z)
from verySmallTable vst join
     table t
     on t.x = vst.x
group by t.y;
```

For this, you want an index on `table(x, y, z)` -- with the columns in that order.

Comment: A FK in  `verySmallTable` pointing to `table` wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova . . . Actually, it could confuse the optimizer.  You really want a full table scan on the full table and then index look ups in the big table.

Comment: What i tried to explained is that i'm using variants of the query, on different fields for example. Which will require me to create manually large number of indexes. I'm not trying to optimize this particular query, i'm looking for a solution that will do this for me (the same way tableau does this for me).